# Install nodejs without package manager

Tags: nodejs

I've downloaded  nodejs I want to  install it on Ubuntu 16.10 ,I have the node folder  with this files

```
bin  CHANGELOG.md  include  lib  LICENSE  README.md  share
```

Where I have to place it to use node?

Comment: see https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: ps: also see https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

Answer (score 2):

You can place them anywhere and link to a bin folder. The common places are `/usr/share`, `/usr/local/share`. On my personal computer, I usually place things like that in my home directory like that: `~/bin/node/*`.

However, I would generally not recommend it with node, unless you have no choice. I would rather go with [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). This way you can install any version of node you want and switch them if needed.

Comment: ~/bin is already in $PATH. Just create ~/bin if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: yeah, but I never put binaries directly in ~/bin. Rather folders, but yeah, you could symlink ~/bin/node -> ~/bin/nodejs/bin/node

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was trying to convince @George of that.

Answer (score 0):

Let give this simple method:

1. Create a folder `/home/$USERNAME/devenv`
2. Download binaries into folder in step `1`
3. `untar` the node file
4. Create a symbolic link in the `/home/$USERNAME/devenv`

   ```
   ln -s untared-node-file-name node
   ```
5. Place it in your path in the `/home/$USERNAME/.profile` file with at the end:

   ```
   PATH=$PATH:$HOME/devenv/node/bin
   ```
6. Source the `/home/$USERNAME/.profile` by running this in terminal:

   ```
   source ~/.profile
   ```
7. Now check with `node -v` and `npm -v`

Information:

- To update just download new version and change symbolic link.

Comment: No need to create the denenv dir, link it, and edit .profile. Just create ~/bin, and it's already in the $PATH.

Comment: Yes if you don't need the extra luggage, but I prefer to group things

Comment: Just drop folders into ~/bin and you can still group things by folder name. No?

Comment: Can you be more explicit?

Comment: It sounds like to keep things organized, you're creating new folders (devenv) in your home directory. That can get kind of messy, yes? Instead, drop the nodejs folder into ~/bin, and if need be, create a link in ~/bin that points to the executable in the folder. Type `echo $PATH` to see the current path, and you'll see that ~/bin is the first item.

Comment: I believe this is better?

Comment: Well... I guess not then...  :-( You don't have to create new folders for every new binary, and you don't have to edit .profile or source .profile. Drag a new folder into ~/bin, and create a new link, *sounds* easier :-)

Comment: Could you please edit my answeer so I get what your trying to put across

Comment: Mat's answer is almost the same idea... except I put the folder containing the binary (or the executable or shell script) into the ~/bin directly, and then link into a folder hierarchy if need be.